# Working With Array Of Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, recursion, lodash

I have an array of objects that can contain children of the same object type, like this:

```
var exampleArray = [
    {
        alias: 'alias1',
        children: [
            {
                alias: 'child1'
            },
            {
                alias: 'child2',
                children: [
                    {
                        alias: 'child4'
                    },
                    {
                        alias: 'child5'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                alias: 'child3'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        alias: 'alias2'
    },
    {
        alias: 'alias3',
        children: [
            {
                alias: 'child6'
            },
            {
                alias: 'child7'
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

The base object has other properties but they are not important to the question(s) at hand. For now, lets just assume the objects can be:

```
{
    alias: 'string',
    children: []
}
```

*The children are optional.*

I am looking for the best methods / fastest methods for managing some things with an object like this. I have created some recursive methods to do some of the things I want, but I want to know if there are better ways to go about doing the following tasks:

1. hasAlias(arr, alias) - I need to determine if the entire object contains any object with the give alias.

Currently, I do this recursively but given that this array can grow finitely, the recursive method is eventually going to hit stack limits.

2. getParent(arr, alias) - I need to be able to obtain the parent that contains an element with the given alias. Given that alias' are unique to the entire array, there will never be two of the same alias. Again I do this recursively right now but I want to find better methods of doing this.
3. deleteObject(arr, alias) - I am unsure how to accomplish this one  currently. I need to be able to pass an array and an alias and have that object (and all its children) removed from the given array. I started a recursive method of doing this but stopped and decided to post here instead.

I am using Node.js and have lodash available for faster methods of doing things. I'm still fairly new to JavaScript so I am unsure if there are better ways to go about doing things with larger scale arrays like this.

Comment: I think you can break the whole array into two or three and call your current method separately. This way you can go through an specif one. You will have a good improvement.

Comment: Not sure I'd do it this way, but as a sidenote `hasAlias` *could* be done with something like `JSON.stringify(arr).indexOf('alias')` if the word `alias` doesn't appear anywhere else etc.

Comment: I think recursive makes sense, it is unlikely you'd hit the stack limit unless you have thousands of nested children. You can always try to make it tail recursive and trampoline it, or run a transpiler to convert it to a loop.

Comment: Would you consider indeces to speed things up? Current versions of Node.js list support for [Map and WeakMap](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/es6/) which could be useful in this regard but complexity of how to construct and maintain an index would be introduced.

Comment: I can't alter how the objects are since they are predefined data out of my hands to edit the model of.

Answer (score 1):

Back in the days of FORTRAN which didn't support recursion, one achieved similar effects by changing a data set to simulate a level of "recursion". Applying this principle to the example object structure, a function to lookup an object by its "alias" (a name or id by another word) could be written without recursion like this:

```
function findAlias( parent, alias) // parent object, alias value string
{   function frame( parent)
    {   return {parent: parent, children: parent.children,
        index: 0, length: parent.children.length};
    }
    var stack, tos, child, children, i;

    stack = [];
    if( parent.children)
        stack.push( frame( parent));

    search:
    while( stack.length)
    {   tos = stack.pop();  // top of generation stack
        children = tos.children;
        for( i = tos.index; i < tos.length; ++i)
        {   child = children[i]; 
            if( child.alias == alias)
            {   return { parent: tos.parent, child: child, childIndex: i}
            }
            if( child.children)
            {   tos.index = i + 1;
                stack.push(tos);  // put it back
                stack.push( frame(child));
                continue search;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

In short one ends up creating a stack of smallish data objects which are pushed and popped in the same function instead of making recursive calls. The example above returns and object with `parent` and `child` object values. The child value is the one with the supplied alias property, and the parent object is the one with the child in its `children` array.

It returns null if the alias could not be found so can be used for `hasAlias` functionality. If it doesn't return null it performs the `getParent` functionality. You do have to create a root node however:

```
// create a rootnode
var rootNode = { alias: "root", children: exampleArray}; 
var found = findAlias(rootNode, "alias3");
if( found)
{  console.log("%s is a child of %s, childIndex = %s",
       found.child.alias, found.parent.alias, found.childIndex);
}
else
   console.log("not found");
```

---

*[Edit: add childIndex to search return object, update test example code, add conclusion.]*

**Conclusion**

Using recursive function calls when supported for a tree walking application makes sense in terms of self documenting code and maintainability.  A non recursive variation may pay for itself it if it can be shown that it has significant benefits in reducing server load under volume pressure tests, but requires sound documentation.

Regardless of internal coding, a tree walking function which returns an object with details of parent, child, and child index values might contribute to overall program efficiency by reducing the total number of treewalks ever performed:

- truthiness of the search return value substitutes for an `hasAlias` function
- the return object from the search can be passed to update, remove or insert functions without requiring repeated tree searches in each function.

Comment: it constantly keeps allocating memory on every search. on the server can be deadly. on the client only gets sluggish

Answer (score 1):

The guaranteed fastest way is obviously to have

```
- an index for the aliases (thats actually a unique id)
- have a parent backlink on each child item (if it has a parent)
```

You look up against the id index

```
var index = {}
(function build(parent) {
   index[parent.alias] = parent;
   (parent.children || []).forEach( item => {
       item.parent = parent
       build(item)
   })
})(objectRoot)


function hasAlias(alias) { return alias in index }

function getAlias(alias) { return index[alias] } 

function getParent(alias) { return index[alias] && index[alias].parent}
```

Deleting an alias would mean removing it and its children from the index and from the parent that still remains in the index

```
function deleteAlias(alias) {

   function deleteFromIndex(item) {
      delete index[item.alias]
      (item.children || []).forEach(deleteFromIndex)
   }
   var item = index[alias]
   item.parent.children.splice(item.parent.children.indexOf(item))
   deleteFromIndex(item)

}
```

Answer (score -1):

I might approach your main array slightly differently, and keep it as a flat array that references other items rather than incorporates them entirely.

```
var flat = [
    {
        alias : "str1",
        children : [ flat[1], flat[2] ],
        parent : null   
    },

    {
        alias : "str1",
        children : [],
        parent : flat[0]    
    },

    {
        alias : "str1",
        children : [],
        parent : flat[0]    
    }
]
```

This is kind of a "[linked list](https://www.google.com/search?q=linked%20list&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)" approach. There are pros and cons to linked lists, but you'll be able to iterate over all items quickly.